# scipy optimize minimize for real time optimization

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, control-theory

I thought of using scipy optimize to optimize some parameters of a system running in real time.
In each iteration the function to optimize would change system parameters wait a bit, and then return some system metric

Is scipy.optimize suitable for such a thing, or better apply some system controller optimizer with feedback loops, etc,...

Thanks

A.

Comment: The standard numerical optimization techniques are not suitable for real time optimization tasks.

Comment: Any recommedations ? For real time optimization

Comment: You need to setup an MPC controller.